# How to calculate dividend yield for the Dow Jones Industrial Average (DJIA) index?

Tags: calculation, dividends, market-indexes, yield

This should be fairly straightforward.

How do I calculate the dividend yield myself for the Dow 30 / Dow Jones Industrial Average (DJIA)?

I'm thinking I just add the last dividend for all the stocks together and divide them by the DJIA.

My real question is, do I have to do anything else with the divisor?

Thank you in advance.  Just trying to get a quick answer.

Comment: The DIA ETF tracks the Dow. Its dividend yield will be similar to the Dow.

Comment: I've made this question's title specific to the DJIA, since it is a price-weighted index and the answer wouldn't apply to other kinds of indexes.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what you'll need to do.

Following the formula of:

Dividend Yield = *(Annual Dividends per Share)* / *(Price per Share)*

All you will need to do is plug in:

*(Sum of annual dividends per share for each company in the DJIA)* 
/ 
*(DJIA value)* To get your answer.

Source:
http://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/dividendyield.asp

Comment: Thank you! I'll do that. Thanks for the reference to investopedia too.

Comment: I found conflicting information.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find a description of the calculation at:

- [Investopedia - Definition of 'Dow Jones Industrial Average (DJIA) Yield'](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/djia_yield.asp).

Quote:

> The aggregate dividend yield on the 30 stocks that make up the Dow
>   Jones Industrial Average. The DJIA yield is calculated by adding the
>   dividends of all 30 component stocks, dividing the result by the
>   price-weighted DJIA index value and factoring in the Dow multiplier.
>   [...]

Comment: Thanks Chris, How would I go about "factoring in the Dow multiplier?"

Comment: I'm assuming they mean multiply by it.

Comment: Nope. It's truly a divisor. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DJIA_divisor Why divide by say .125 and not multiply by 8? I can't say. But I remember in May of '86 when the divisor changed (as it does regularly) from being a number above one to under. So it may be for consistency.